# Proof by induction that sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, induction

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence, where $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+1/a_n$. Show by induction that $3/2\leq a_n \leq 2$ when $n \geq 2$.

This is what I have so far:

1. Check if true for $n=2$

$$a_2 = 1+1/1 = 2\Rightarrow 3/2 \leq 2 \leq 2 \space \space  \checkmark$$

2. Assume true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$
3. Prove true for all $n+1$

$$3/2 \leq a_n \leq 2 \Rightarrow 1/2\leq 1/a_n \leq 2/3$$
$$\Rightarrow3/2\leq 1 + 1/a_n \leq 5/3$$ $$\Rightarrow 3/2 \leq a_{n+1}\leq 5/3 < 2$$
$$\Rightarrow 3/2 \leq a_{n+1} < 2$$

The problem is that I need to show that $a_{n+1} \leq 2$ and not $a_{n+1} < 2$. Did I do something wrong in step 3 of my induction proof, or is there an alternative way to show that the statement is true for all $n+1$?

Comment: If $x < 2$, then $x \leq 2$.

Comment: You do not assume, in step 2, that the property is true for all $n\ge 2$. What you assume is that it is true for some $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Note if you assume in step 2 that its true FOR ALL $n \geq 2$, then you're just assuming that the statement is true. You should assume its true for SOME $n \geq 2$ and show that it implies that its true for $n+1$. Then this together with the base case is what will give it for all $n \geq 2$.

Also if $x < y$, then $x \leq y$. (the symbol $\leq$ just means less than or equal to - in particular less than falls in this category).

Comment: Ah yes, of course :) Thank you J126, GReyes, and PStheman

Comment: You should also pay attention to the other comments about you assuming what you are trying to prove.